# Overide the Stylesheet of a RSS Java Script

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

learning CSS, HTML & Java as I go on a project.. Mashing other people's code together, then editing it to fit my purpose. It's how I learn.

So, 
I'm embedding a RSS feed into my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://output69.rssinclude.com/output?type=js&amp;id=491322&amp;hash=e7ec1e6d8d00e9c28972fedae169e932"></script>
```

and although the style is close..it's for a WebApp. I've copied the style sheet from the source (unfortunately I can't make the changes I want at the source)
then changed the parameters I need, then pasted it as a style in my page:

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<style type="text/css">

div#rssincl -box-491322 * {
    font-family : Verdana, Arial, sans-serif !important;
    margin : 0 !important;
    padding : 0 !important;
    border-radius : 10px !important;
    line-height : 110% !important;
    clear : both !important;
}


div#rssincl -box-491322 {
    height : 520px !important;
    border-radius : 10px !important;
    overflow-y : auto !important;
}


div#rssincl -box-491322 div.rss-head {
    border-radius : 10px !important;
    padding : 7px !important;
    background-color : #ffffff !important;
}


div#rssincl -box-491322 div.rss-head p.rss-title, div#rssincl -box-491322 div.rss-head p.rss-title a {
    font-family : Verdana, Arial, sans-serif !important;
    border-radius : 10px !important ;
    font-size : 15px !important;
    font-weight : bold !important;
    text-align : center !important;
    color : #000000 !important;
    text-decoration : none !important;
}


div#rssincl -box-491322 div.rss-content {
    border-radius : 5px !important;
}


div#rssincl -box-491322 div.rss-content div.rss-entry {
    border-radius : 10px !important;
    padding : 7px !important;
    background-color : rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) !important;
    border-bottom : 3px solid #FFFFFF !important;
}


div#rssincl -box-491322 div.rss-content div.rss-last {
    border-bottom : none !important;
    border-radius : 10px !important;
}


div#rssincl -box-491322 div.rss-content div.rss-entry p.rss-itemtitle {
    margin-bottom : 6px !important;
    border-radius : 10px !important;
    text-align : center !important;
}


div#rssincl -box-491322 div.rss-content div.rss-entry p.rss-itemtitle a {
    font-family : Verdana, Arial, sans-serif !important;
    border-radius : 10px !important;
    font-size : 13px !important;
    text-decoration : underline !important;
    text-align : centre !important;
    font-weight : bold !important;
    color : #000000 !important;
}


div#rssincl -box-491322 div.rss-content div.rss-entry div.rss-itemdesc, div#rssincl -box-491322 div.rss-content div.rss-entry div.rss-itemdesc * {
    border-radius : 10px !important;
    font-family : Verdana, Arial, sans-serif !important;
    font-size : 12px !important;
    color : #000000 !important;
}


div#rssincl -box-491322 div.rss-content div.rss-entry div.rss-backlink {
    border-radius : 10px !important;
    font-family : ;font-size: 10px !important;
    color : #000000 !important;
}


div#rssincl -box-491322 div.rss-content div.rss-entry div.rss-backlink a {
    border-radius : 10px !important;
    color : #000000 !important;
    line-height : 130% !important;
    text-decoration : none !important;
}


div#rssincl -box-491322 div.rss-content div.rss-entry div.rss-itemdesc img {
    border-radius : 10px !important;
    margin : 5px !important;
}


div#rssincl -box-491322 div.rss-content div.rss-entry div.rss-clear {
    border-radius : 10px !important;
    clear : both !important;
}


</style>
```

from some googling I thought !important in front of everything may work. It didn't. the page still displays original formatting from the script.

Explanations in simple terms are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you made a typo in your css to me.

Your code:

```css
div#rssincl -box-491322
```

What I think it should be:

```css
div#rssincl-box-491322
```

Note the extra space in your code. It appears to be a problem on all of your selectors.

Comment: I just noticed that, I have had to rectify that a few times. Still hasn't made a difference

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are not able to get your styles reflected on your webpage.
Maybe you can try inspecting elements in firebug. When you hover on any element then on the right window of firebug (i.e. css window) you can figure out what is getting wrong. If your styles are overidden then that property will be strikethrough.

Other than that, I don't think there is anything which can ovrride `!important` but possible chances are that there are styles applied from your script.

Comment: Okay. It seems to be a combination. I used firebug and saw i'd missed rssincl- from my div tags. 

also the spaces in the div#rss-... are a problem. However, everytime I remove the space in the code above it is automatically put back in. I cannot figure out why!

I'm using maqetta.